# I can't initiate react native example project

Tags: react-native

When I followed React Native Tutorial, I tried
`terminal
$ react-native init AwsomeProject
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/myname/Projects/AwsomeProject
/`

It got stuck, it generated some files.such as `package.json`, directory `node_modules`, without `AwesomeProject/AwesomeProject.xcodeproj`

My environment is

`OSX 10.10.5
nodejs v2.5.0
Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.10_for_Xcode_6.4
Xcode 6.4`

Did I miss something? There was no error/warning at all.

Comment: Same error for me as well..

Comment: I have this same issue. sudo didn't help. I just get the node_modules folder and package.json but no ios folder or xcode project anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking at the wrong place, the file `AwesomeProject.xcodeproj` will be there at `AwesomeProject/ios/AwesomeProject.xcodeproj`.

Comment: According to react-native tutorial, the file should locate at `AwesomeProject/AwesomeProject.xcodeproj`

Comment: @rocLv Go to this page https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#setup there it mentions `AwesomeProject/iOS/AwesomeProject.xcodeproj` . However you can check for file's location inside your project also.

Answer (score 0):

You should try deleting the project and running init again with sudo.
Make sure you have xcode 6 or higher, and you have the latest node installed.

Answer (score 0):

According to Facebook's [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content) walk-thru, you need Node version 4 or greater.

When you have the incorrect version (I had < 1.0.0), the project file structure compiles differently.

@rocLv's comment elucidates.

If everything is go, open the project at ios/AwesomeProject.xcodeproj